# Xamarin.Android Not Receiving Location Updates in Direct Boot Mode

Tags: android, xamarin.android, location

### TLDR: is it possible to access location in Direct Boot mode?

I want to receive location updates for a device (testing on Pixel 3a) when the phone boots. This is a companion feature for a regular app, so assume required permission grants etc are taken care of.

The following code is also taken from components that work fine when invoked from a MainActivity.

The steps to set up the location callbacks are as follows:

Firstly, a DirectBootAware BroadcastReceiver that listens for ACTION_LOCKED_BOOT_COMPLETED means I can run code when the device boot and before the screen is unlocked.

```
[BroadcastReceiver(Enabled = true, Exported = true, DirectBootAware = true)]
[IntentFilter(new string[] { Intent.ActionLockedBootCompleted })]
public class StartForegroundServiceReceiver : BroadcastReceiver
{
    public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
```

From here I can verify that the permissions for Corse and Fine location are granted (which they are!)

```
var permissionCheckResult = context.CheckSelfPermission(Manifest.Permission.AccessFineLocation);

Android.Util.Log.Info("TestingTag", $"AccessFineLocation CheckSelfPermission {permissionCheckResult.ToString()}");


permissionCheckResult = context.CheckSelfPermission(Manifest.Permission.LocationHardware);

Android.Util.Log.Info("TestingTag", $"LocationHardware CheckSelfPermission {permissionCheckResult.ToString()}");


permissionCheckResult = context.CheckSelfPermission(Manifest.Permission.AccessCoarseLocation);

Android.Util.Log.Info("TestingTag", $"AccessCoarseLocation CheckSelfPermission {permissionCheckResult.ToString()}");
```

and that the Network, GPS, and Passive Location Providers are enabled (again, they're all enabled!)

```
var locationManager = (LocationManager)context.GetSystemService(Context.LocationService);

var enabled = locationManager.IsProviderEnabled(LocationManager.PassiveProvider);
Log.Info("TestingTag", $"PassiveProvider IsProviderEnabled {(enabled ? "yes" : "no")}");

enabled = locationManager.IsProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GpsProvider);
Log.Info("TestingTag", $"GpsProvider IsProviderEnabled {(enabled ? "yes" : "no")}");

enabled = locationManager.IsProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NetworkProvider);
Log.Info("TestingTag", $"NetworkProvider IsProviderEnabled {(enabled ? "yes" : "no")}");
```

If I check `GetLastKnownLocation`

```
var location = locationManager.GetLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GpsProvider);

if (location == null)
{
    location = locationManager.GetLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NetworkProvider);
}

if (location == null)
{
    location = locationManager.GetLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.PassiveProvider);
}

if (location == null)
    Log.Error("TestingTag", $"Location is null");
```

This always returns null, perhaps because the device has just booted? Or maybe it's because of the same root cause as not receiving any location updates?

Finally, I register for location updates with the `LocationManager`

```
var callback = new LocationCallback();

Log.Info("TestingTag", "Starting RequestLocationUpdates via PassiveProvider..");
locationManager.RequestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.PassiveProvider, 3000, 3, callback);

Log.Info("TestingTag", "Starting RequestLocationUpdates via GpsProvider..");
locationManager.RequestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GpsProvider, 3000, 3, callback);

Log.Info("TestingTag", "Starting RequestLocationUpdates via NetworkProvider..");
locationManager.RequestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NetworkProvider, 3000, 3, callback);
```

Here's the location callback code:

```
public class LocationCallback : ScanCallback, Android.Locations.ILocationListener
{
    public void OnLocationChanged(Location location)
    {
        Log.Info("TestingTag", $"OnLocationChanged {location.Latitude} ~ {location.Longitude}");
    }

    public void OnProviderDisabled(string provider)
    {
        Log.Info("TestingTag", $"OnProviderDisabled {provider}");
    }

    public void OnProviderEnabled(string provider)
    {
        Log.Info("TestingTag", $"OnProviderEnabled {provider}");
    }

    public void OnStatusChanged(string provider, [GeneratedEnum] Availability status, Bundle extras)
    {
        Log.Info("TestingTag", $"OnStatusChanged {provider} ~ {status.ToString()}");
    }
}
```

The callback is never invoked :-(

I've added a `BluetoothManager` to scan for BLE signals (omitted code for that) and that works, ScanResults are returned fine and the phone / BroadcastReceiver is still alive. So it's not as if the BroadcastReceiver is just dying...

Any tips / suggestions / or confirmation that what I'm trying to do is not possible would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Based on my research, get the location data in the direct boot mode, this behavior is related to the access data, you should use use device encrypted storage. And device encrypted storage contains data encrypted with a key that is only available after a device has performed a successful verified boot. it is impossible to access location in Direct Boot mode. You can refer to this link.https://developer.android.com/training/articles/direct-boot?hl=en-us

Comment: Hi Leon, when I ask about location in the original post I'm talking location services i.e. GPS etc, not a storage location. 

The article you reference talks about data storage location and disc encryption. 

Are you saying that location services (i.e. the LocationManager class and its methods) are dependent on access to User Encrypted Storage?

Comment: Hi Rob, have you gotten an answer to this? Is it really not possible?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get a valid location in DirectBoot mode with `LocationManager` on my Android Q device. I'm calling from a `Service` and not a `BroadcastReceiver`, though I don't think that should make a difference.

Here's the manifest entry for my `Service`:

```xml
<service android:name=".IncomingMessageService"
  android:directBootAware="true"
  android:exported="false">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
  </intent-filter>
</service>
```

and my Kotlin code:

```kotlin
suspend fun getLocation(context: Context): Location? {
  return suspendCoroutine { continuation ->
    context.getSystemService<LocationManager>()?.run {
      val criteria = Criteria().apply {
        accuracy = Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE
        isAltitudeRequired = false
        isBearingRequired = false
        isSpeedRequired = false
      }
      if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
        getBestProvider(criteria, true)?.let {
          getCurrentLocation(
            it,
            null,
            context.mainExecutor,
            {
              continuation.resume(it)
            })
        } ?: continuation.resume(null)
      } else {
        @Suppress("DEPRECATION")
        requestSingleUpdate(
          criteria,
          {
            continuation.resume(it)
          },
          null
        )
      }
    } ?: continuation.resume(null)
  }
}
```

Note that `requestSingleUpdate()` is deprecated in API 30 and replaced with the new call `getCurrentLocation()`.

Also note that using [`LocationServices`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationServices) from Google Play services (instead of LocationManager) did *not* work in DirectBoot mode for me. It complained that "LocationServices.API is not available on this device", though it works fine after sign in.

Make sure to review the [requirements and limitations of using background location accesses](https://developer.android.com/training/location/background).